# TypeScript/React. How to check returned value of internal function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So, I have a simple SFC Component, where I cannot check how my func `bulidLinksList` works. Even when I try to add a type checking `IMethods` - it throw me an error:

> Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'IMethods'.
>   Property 'bulidLinksList' is missing in type 'Element[]'.

Interface:

```
export interface IMethods {
  bulidLinksList: () => JSX.Element[]
}
```

Component:

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from './Link'
import { IProps, IMethods } from './types'
import styles from './index.scss'

const Links: React.SFC<IProps> = ({ links = [] }) => {

  if (!links || links.length === 0) return null

  const bulidLinksList = (): IMethods => {
    return links.map((link, i) => ( // TS show an error there
      <Link key={i} {...link} />
    ))
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.linksContainer}>
      {bulidLinksList()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: What is the type of IMethods? Note that you're saying that your function *returns* an IMethods, not that it's a member of an instance of it.

Comment: @y2bd sorry, but I do not understand what do you mean...

Comment: Try `export type IMethods = JSX.Element[]`

Comment: @estus no, I also tried this. It does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current implementation of `bulidLinksList` is expecting a variable with the shape defined by the `IMethods` interface. The compiler is upset that an array of elements is being returned instead.

One solution might be to redefine the `IMethods` type definition.

Another solution would be to simply adjust the expected return value of the `bulidLinksList` function.

Although the explicitly defined return value renders the use of typing optional, in this particular instance.

See below for a practical example of each.

```
// Solution 1 - Redefine IMethods Definition.
type IMethods = JSX.Elements[]

// Solution 2 - Adjust Expected Return Value Type.
const bulidLinksList = (): JSX.Element[] => links.map((link, i) => <Link key={i} {...link}/>)
```

Comment: Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to type it any further:

```
  const bulidLinksList = () => {
    return links.map((link, i) => (
      <Link key={i} {...link} />
    ))
  }
```

is implicitly typed, `bulidLinksList` type is `() => JSX.Element[]`.

`IMethods` cannot be applied to `bulidLinksList` because there should be an object with  `bulidLinksList` method and there's no such object.